# How can I program different keyboard handling for each view in my Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

In the main panel of my application I have a `textView`. When user presses it, the keyboard appears and I have to modify the constraints on this panel so that the keyboard doesn't overlay anything. For that purpose I attached an observer in `viewDidLoad` method of that class:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: 
    #selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame),
    name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

and then I have a method:

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification: NSNotification) {
```

that handles everything.

Now, on different panel I want to modify my constraints in a different way, so I prepared a different method for that:

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrameInOtherWay(notification: NSNotification) {
```

and now to support that on that view, I have to attach it to the observer. But when I wrote in viewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: 
    #selector(keyboardWillChangeFrameInOtherWay), name:        
    UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

then when keyboard appears on the 2nd panel - both methods fire (from the 1st panel and the 2nd one). How can I run only one method for a specific panel?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's an important detail here, but both views are embedded in navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my answer since I discovered the problem here, I hope it's the best way of handling this issue. I added this piece of code on the first panel:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

also, since it's embedded in navigation controller, I moved this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame),
name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

to `viewWillAppear` and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't clearly understand your question, btw you can access the `object` field of a `NSNotification`. If you pass an object to the `NSNotificationCenter` then you will receive it and you can perform one method or the other one. Another possibility is to remove and add every time the observer, so that the Controller that own the textField will observes only one per time...